# Working on .mdf and .sdf at the same time

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-ce, ssms

Is it possible to open .mdf and .sdf database types in the same Sql Sever Management Studio session?

I have tried, and it obviously did not work. I am guessing I either have something configured wrong or they are not compatible. I can open each up separately of course using the appropriate database provider when opening SSMS.

I was just hoping there was a way or maybe some other MS tool, plug in or app I don't have that will allow them to work together.

I was hoping to use TSQL to populate the Compact Db but it appears I need to code up an app or something to do this. Any suggestions on porting data to compact?

Comment: Use my free Visual Studio add-in "SQL Server Compact Toolbox", lets you move data and schema from SQL Server to Compact in a single click!

Comment: Will they work with VS2012 Pro?

Comment: Looks like the best thing out there. Loaded it love it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use my free Visual Studio add-in "SQL Server Compact Toolbox", lets you move data and schema from SQL Server to Compact in a single click